# Android - Play Store - Change expiration date of a subscription

Tags: android, node.js, subscription

**I want to change the expiration date of a Subscription** in my Play Store using the **Play Store API**.

I have a Mobile App where you can buy a renewal Play Store Subscription or you can get some time for free from Promos in app.

The main problem here is that **if you have bought a subscription from the Play Store** and you want to **add time by a Promo in the application,** **I can't change the Renewal date of your subscription** to handle this new time added into your Premium. So, the Play Store is going to renew your subscription and take the payment in a wrong date.

***How can I handle this situation??***

> ***iOS CASE:*** [iOS - App Store - Change expiration date of a subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091930/ios-app-store-change-expiration-date-of-a-subscription)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem, is use **Defer**.
With this we can modify the next billing date, and move it to the future the days we need.

***Documentation***
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/defer