# iOS - App Store - Change expiration date of a subscription

Tags: node.js, app-store, subscription

I want to change the expiration date of a Subscription in my Play Store using the Play Store API.

I have a Mobile App where you can buy a renewal **App Store Subscription** or you can get some time for free from Promos in app.

The main problem here is that **if you have bought a subscription from the App Store and you want to add time by a Promo in the application, I can't change the Renewal date of your subscription to handle this new time added into your Premium**. So, the App Store is going to renew your subscription and take the payment in a wrong date.

How can I handle this situation??

> ***Android CASE:*** [Android - Play Store - Change expiration date of a subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058379/android-play-store-change-expiration-date-of-a-subscription)

Comment: Any idea for this solution?!